# What is causing the text to remain when drawing a doughnut animation in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

※All of this is translated from Japanese to English by deepl translation, so the sentences may not be correct. Please understand that the sentences may not be correct.

I found a YouTube video of a 3D doughnut animation being drawn on a terminal, and since the video was coded in C, I was trying to port the C language to Rust, which I am currently studying, but for some reason it is not working.

YouTube Movie => https://youtu.be/rj7DOPPTkQA

Based on this video, the code ported from C to Rust is written below.

Here is a YouTube video of it in Rust, which I ported from c
YouTube => https://youtu.be/_Hmy74esH_I

```
use std::{thread, time};
use clearscreen;

#[warn(unused_must_use)]
fn main() {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = stdout.lock();

    let mut A: f32 = 0.0;
    let mut B: f32 = 0.0;
    let mut i: f32 = 0.0;
    let mut j: f32 = 0.0;
    let mut z: [f32; 1760] = [0.0; 1760];
    let mut b: [char; 1760] = [' '; 1760];

    loop {
        unsafe {
            let b_ptr = b.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
            let z_ptr = z.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
            std::ptr::write_bytes(b_ptr, 32u8, 1760);
            std::ptr::write_bytes(z_ptr, 0u8, 7040);
            j = 0.0;
            while 6.28 > j {
                i = 0.0;
                while 6.28 > i {
                    let c: f32 = f32::sin(i);
                    let d: f32 = f32::cos(j);
                    let e: f32 = f32::sin(A);
                    let f: f32 = f32::sin(j);
                    let g: f32 = f32::cos(A);
                    let h: f32 = d + 2.0;
                    let D: f32 = 1.0 / (c * h * e + f * g + 5.0);
                    let l: f32 = f32::cos(i);
                    let m: f32 = f32::cos(B);
                    let n: f32 = f32::sin(B);
                    let t: f32 = c * h * g - f * e;
                    let x: i32 = (40.0 + 30.0 * D * (l * h * m - t * n)) as i32;
                    let y = (12.0 + 15.0 * D * (l * h * n + t * m)) as i32;
                    let o = x + 80 * y;
                    let N = (8.0 * ((f * e - c * d * g) * m - c * d * e - f * g - l * d * n)) as i32;
                    if 22 > y && y > 0 && x > 0 && 80 > x && D > z[o as usize] {
                        z[o as usize] = D;
                        let str: Vec<char> = vec!['.', ',', '-', '~', ':', ';', '=', '!', '*', '#', '$', '@'];
                        let result:char = if N > 0 { str[ N as usize ] } else { ' ' };
                        b[o as usize] = result;
                    }
                    i += 0.02;
                }
                j += 0.07;
            }

            let mut k = 0;
            while k < 1761 {
                let result = if k % 80 != 0 { b[k] as char } else { '\n' };
                handle.write(&[result as u8]).unwrap();
                A += 0.00004;
                B += 0.00002;
                k += 1;
            }

            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(30));
            clearscreen::clear().unwrap();

        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in the video I uploaded, the text in the area where the doughnut animation is drawn will remain, compared to the doughnut animation written in the c language.

Sorry for the lack of clarity.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me if you are an expert.

The only thing I could think of was to try changing the bank number of the memory set, or increasing or decreasing the size of the array.

Comment: [While you can use machine translation, you must always ensure the result is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions).

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what your comment means.

Comment: The english is fine except for "changing the bank number of the memory set". Not sure what that means, but the question remains understandable. You should translate C `char` into Rust `u8`, and use `u8` literal syntax like this: `b'.'`. That's probably the issue, but the code is hard to read because of all the one-letter variables.

Comment: I changed from char to u8 and it works ideally!
Sorry for the ugly code...
Thank you for teaching me how to do this!

Comment: Is that what you meant?
My apologies.

Comment: @SvenMarnach click the link.

Comment: @SvenMarnach No, I referred to the translation between natural language. I didn't check the resulted English (in fact, I didn't even read the question), I just noted since the OP said this was a machine translation that such thing is only allowed if you manually verify the result.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I actually missed that part of the question.